# When is a schedule active the next time?

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone, momentjs, luxon

We are trying to solve a somewhat simple question, but are struggling with finding a good code solution:

> Given weekdays, minutes, start date, end date and current time plus timezone - how long, in seconds, until the schedule becomes active for the next time, i.e. all conditions are met

- weekdays: given as array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
- minutes: given as array [0,1,2,...1439] (a day has 1440 minutes, if "7" is in the array then the minute 00:07 until 00:08 activates the schedule)
- start date: Given as "YYYY-MM-DD"
- end date: Given as "YYYY-MM-DD"
- current time: Given as e.g. unix timestamp
- timezone: E.g. "America/Vancouver" - note that these dictate time changes

All conditions are met for a given time when:

- the weekday for that time in the given timezone is part of the weekday array
- the minute for that time is the given timezone is part of the minute array and
- the date for that time in the given timezone is between the start and end date (inclusive)

I'm posting a function that somewhat works, but I am very unsure about correctness. It also feels extremely complicated. Is there an easier way to solve the question?

We are currently using luxon, but are open to other libraries:

```js
// Returns 0 if schedule currently active, otherwise seconds until next active or null if no future active
export const checkActive = ({
  startDate,
  endDate,
  minutes,
  weekDays,
  timezone,
  now = null
}) => {
  const nowAtTimezone = now === null
    ? DateTime.local().setZone(timezone)
    : DateTime.fromMillis(new Date(now) / 1).setZone(timezone);

  // Important: new Date('YYYY-MM-DD') creates the date in UTC, not in local timezone
  const nowDateObj = new Date(nowAtTimezone.toISODate());
  const startDateObj = new Date(startDate);
  const endDateObj = new Date(endDate === null ? '9999-01-01' : endDate);

  const nowDateActive = startDateObj <= nowDateObj;
  const nowMinute = nowAtTimezone.hour * 60 + nowAtTimezone.minute;
  let startMinuteIdx = nowDateActive ? minutes.findIndex((m) => m >= nowMinute) : 0;

  for (
    // IMPORTANT: date here is always in UTC
    let date = nowDateActive ? nowDateObj : startDateObj;
    date <= endDateObj;
    date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + 1)
  ) {
    if (startMinuteIdx !== -1 && weekDays.includes(date.getUTCDay())) {
      const datetime = DateTime.fromObject({
        year: date.getUTCFullYear(),
        month: date.getUTCMonth() + 1,
        day: date.getUTCDate()
      }, { zone: timezone });
      while (startMinuteIdx < minutes.length) {
        const startMinute = minutes[startMinuteIdx];
        const hour = Math.floor(startMinute / 60);
        const minute = startMinute % 60;
        const startTime = datetime.set({ hour, minute });
        if (startTime.hour === hour && startTime.minute === minute) {
          return Math.max(startTime.toSeconds() - Math.floor(nowAtTimezone.toSeconds()), 0);
        }
        startMinuteIdx += 1;
      }
    }
    startMinuteIdx = 0;
  }
  return null;
};
```

Test example:

```js
     {
        startDate: '2022-10-31',
        endDate: '2022-10-31',
        minutes: [
          405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412,
          413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420,
          421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428,
          429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436,
          437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444,
          445, 446, 447, 448, 449
        ],
        weekDays: [
          0, 1, 2, 3,
          4, 5, 6
        ],
        timezone: 'Etc/GMT+12'
      }
```

with a current time of `'2022-10-31T04:56:57.000Z'` we expect the result to be `7 * 60 * 60 + 3 * 60 + 3 + 6 * 60 * 60 + 45 * 60 = 49683`.

Comment: probably want to also include more info about your function arguments, especially for `minutes` - as assumption that this could be minutes since the beginning of the day may be incorrect

Comment: @Tibrogargan Updated with more information. Basically, a minute is to the day what a weekday is to the week.

Comment: Due to Moment's [status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), I suggest using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) for this.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Sure, I've rewritten the function in Luxon. Doesn't change anything about confidence or how complex the function is, unfortunately.